# Sort a collection by another array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a collection of names:

```
[
  {last_name: "A", name: "James" }, 
  {last_name: "A", name: "Robert" }, 
  {last_name: "B", name: "Tim"}, 
  {last_name: "B", name: "Bob" },
  {last_name: "C", name: "Ricky Ticky" }
]
```

Then I have an array with every `last_name` in it, in a particular order:

```
["B", "C", "A"]
```

How can I sort my collection by the order of last_names in my second array?

**What I've tried:**

The best solution I have so far is to create a new array, then loop through my collection of names, pushing all of the elements that match my sort array's first index ("B"), then second index ("C"), and finally "A". Seems verbose or maybe underscore.js has a better method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Underscore's `sortBy` function, that gives you the ability to sort on an arbitrary feature of the array's elements:

```js
var people = [
  {last_name: "A", name: "James" }, 
  {last_name: "A", name: "Robert" }, 
  {last_name: "B", name: "Tim"}, 
  {last_name: "B", name: "Bob" },
  {last_name: "C", name: "Ricky Ticky" }
];

var lastNameOrder = ["B", "C", "A"];

var sortedPeople = _.sortBy(people, function(person) {
  return lastNameOrder.indexOf(person.last_name);
})

console.log(sortedPeople);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could also do one pass over `lastNameOrder` to build a name->index map in an `Object` and then use that `Object` in the `_.sortBy` function. Might be faster, might not, probably not even noticeable with such small data sets though.

Comment: @muistooshort: That is pretty much what `_.sortBy` does - I'd be repeating its work. (It is also the reason for my first comment on Brady's implementation.)

Comment: Not quite. The Schwartzian transform that `sortBy` does will end up calling `indexOf` `people.length` times. If you build the name->index map by hand you wouldn't call `indexOf` at all, you'd just make one pass over `lastNameOrder` rather than `people.length` linear searches through it; you'd end up doing `people.length` lookups into the name->index object instead of all those `indexOf` calls.

Comment: @muistooshort: Oh I see what you're saying now.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done fairly simply with Array.sort().

```
function sortNames(names, order) {
  return names.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (order.indexOf(a.last_name) > order.indexOf(b.last_name)) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
}
```

Array.prototype.sort() will sort your array by comparing two values at a time.  if you return 1, b comes before a; -1, a before b; and zero is no change.

more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: dig the raw JS - trying now

Comment: This is slower than Underscore's implementation, as it invokes `indexOf` at each comparison (probably `O(n log(n))`), and Underscore invokes it once per element (`O(n)`).

Comment: dig the algorithm analysis - in my case speed doesn't matter (small array), but it's good to know

Comment: How come your comparator function never returns a negative value?

Comment: @muistooshort  don't return a negative because it's unnecessary, this meets the requirements with less code and less cpu cycles.

Comment: @muistooshort I believe most implementations ignore the symmetry requirement for the comparator, so if you are willing to take a slight performance hit for unnecessary flipping (I think) and willing to risk things breaking if the spec gets implemented more rigorously, you can sort using a `<=` instead of a `<=>`.

Comment: @BradyCartmell Without returning a negative value, it will certainly fail on certain datasets.

Comment: Your comparator doesn't seem to do anything at all in Safari (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mtp33coe/) whereas one implemented to the spec sorts things as expected (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a6Lonkh6/). What am I missing? Am I missing something obvious @Amadan? It seems to work in Chrome and Firefox though but that's implementation-specific so the code is dodgy at best.

Comment: @torazaburo It fails as-is in Safari, no fiddling with the data required.

Comment: @muistooshort: Yes, that's pretty much exactly what I said - it is implementation-specific, and dodgy. While I did not test on Safari, by your tests Safari seems to really want that symmetry requirement ("If a =CF b, then b =CF a"), while Chrome manages even if it is not satisfied. But this is not the first place I've encountered the practice.

Comment: @Amadan And that's why we follow the specs rather than being lazy and doing the "try it and see what happens" approach. Not only does it avoid implementation-specific behavior in current implementations but it helps to future-proof our code. "Shorter and faster" is sort of useless if it is wrong and I can produce incorrect results faster and with less code than this anyway :) I'm sure you know all this already but you're not the only one reading this.

Comment: @muistooshort I fully agree, I was just trying to explain the practice (since I saw such code before).

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**: because of grave failure

But it still does not sort the names and because I cannot see any reason not to do so

```
var people = [
  {last_name: "A", name: "James" }, 
  {last_name: "A", name: "Robert" }, 
  {last_name: "B", name: "Tim"}, 
  {last_name: "B", name: "Bob" },
  {last_name: "C", name: "Ricky Ticky" }
];

var lastNameOrder = ["B", "C", "A"];

var sortedPeople = people.sort(function(person1,person2){
  var lna =  lastNameOrder.indexOf(person1.last_name);
  var lnb =  lastNameOrder.indexOf(person2.last_name);

  if(lna === lnb){
    return (person1.name < person2.name) ? -1 : 
           (person1.name > person2.name) ?  1 : 0;
  } else {
    return lna-lnb;
  }
})
```

Comment: JS requires a comparator function; `sort(function(element) { ... })` is not correct. If you got the correct result, it is a coincidence; try it with different `lastNameOrder`.

Comment: Yepp, that's true, I did not test it completly. Even my the second example had an error in it!